# Make a loop VBA Excel

Tags: loops

I am new in the blog and I have some trouble with a loop.

I did the next code to generate a random value (Range C4) and keep adding until 100 is reached.

The code works fine but I want to make it in a loop.

Also, There are 3 conditions:
1) If range C6 have a 1 the variable "valor" wil be + 5
2) If range D6 have a 1 the variable "valor" will be - 1
3) If range C6 and range D6 both sum 2: first C6 will get 5 and the total sum will be -1

Is there a way to make it using loop as well? or maybe case if?

Thank you so much with the help!

Cheers
Hector

```
Sub Crashers()

valor = Range("d4").Value 'acumulado

'=========================== VALUES =============================
If valor < 100 Then

Randomize
Range("c4").Value = Int(20 * Rnd) + 1 'a = random

If Range("c6") = 1 Then
valor = valor + (Range("c4").Value + 5)
Range("c6").Value = 0
Range("d4").Value = valor

Else

If Range("d6") = 1 Then
valor = (valor - 1) + Range("c4").Value
Range("d6").Value = 0
Range("d4").Value = valor
Else


If (Range("c6") + Range("d6")) = 0 Then
valor = valor + Range("c4").Value
Range("d4").Value = valor
Else

End If
End If
End If

'   MsgBox "Maximo es " & valor
'=========================== VALUES =============================
Else
    Range("C4:D4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C4").Select

    Range("d4").Value = 0
    Range("c4").Value = 0

End If
End Sub
```